# Boostrap navigation (secondary ul) not responding to custom css borders

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where my bootstrap navigation has an issue with the `border-bottom: **attribute**` in reference to a secondary ul in a drop-down menu.

I wish to have `border-bottom: medium black solid` or similar on the immediately visible part of the navigation (home, pages, quick links etc) but not on the drop-down menus. I have tried the obvious custom css, including the **:not()** selector and other pseudo classes. None of these have worked.

Basic outline:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Pages<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Primary</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Secondary</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/meh/r6byr9td/
To view the expanded navigation, drag the JavaScript section to the left, or view in full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the exact element.  `ul.nav > li`

```
ul.nav > li {
  border-bottom: medium black solid;
}
```